# Crystal Reports - Summary vs. Running Total Field

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports, what is the difference between a running total field and a summary field?

(In the Crystal IDE, Summary fields are located in Insert -> Summary.  Running totals can be added in the Field Explorer)

(Version 11.5)

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, Running Total fields are basically enhanced Summary Fields.

Running Total fields can do everything Summary Fields can, except that Running Total fields can also do the following:

- Evaluate for each record, on change of field, on change of group, or evaluate based on a formula.
- Reset the summary on change of field, on change of group, based on a formula, or never.

Summary Fields, however, can be shown as a percentage of a field, so they're not without their uses (and they're a little easier to set up).